# Searching in an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$fruits = array(
    [0] => array('name'=>'banana', 'color'=>'yellow' , 'shape'=>'cylinder'),
    [1] => array('name'=>'apple', 'color'=>'red' , 'shape'=>'sphere'),
    [2] => array('name'=>'orange', 'color'=>'orange' , 'shape'=>'sphere') 
    )
```

How can I find out if the array `$fruits` already contains `apple` in it?

I have tried: `in_array("apple", $fruits)` and that didn't work out.

I also tried various syntax and messed a bit with `array_key_exists()`, but nothing worked out. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `in_array();`

Comment: I tried in_array() , I guess the best solution as per all the answers I'm getting is a foreach loop..

Comment: checkout my answer. I have used `foreach()` and `in_array()`

Comment: @Mustapha If you use PHP 5.4 or lower, it is the best solution I can think of. But as of PHP 5.5 there is a better method (see my post).

Comment: @Mustapha Check my answer with demo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is notoriously unwieldy in such cases. The best all-around solution is a simple `foreach`:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
    if ($fruit['name'] == 'apple') {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($found) ....
```

You can write this in a number of sexier ways, but all of them will require additional memory allocation and/or will be slower; a good number of them will also be more difficult to understand if you are not very experienced.

Comment: This will work only if you know what the last key's name is going to be.  What if the array had 1000 top level keys and you wanted to see if anywhere in it it contained 'orange'.  If name were 'tangerine' and color were 'orange' this code would miss it. The array is structured. $fruits[0]['name'] == apple. If you don't go through the [0,1,2...etc] it won't work because the first foreach loop only iterates over the first key with a defined key after it.

Comment: @Unipartisandev: I have no idea what you are talking about. The question tackles finding fruits *by name*. We don't care about any other keys.

Comment: @Jon; I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm just being specific to the asker's question: "How can I find out if the array $fruits already contains apple in it?"  What if ['shape'] == 'apple' but ['name'] didn't?  The array $fruits would then contain apple.  In this case, your answer does not help the asker.  That's all.

Comment: @Unipartisandev: Thanks for clarifying. We interpret "if `$fruits` contains apple" differently; ultimately only the OP can answer this authoritatively. I am going with what seems to me to be the desired semantics; doing it the other way would mean that you could search for "orange" and find an apricot.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($fruits as $fruit)
{ 
    /*In first loop $fruit = array('name'=>'banana', 'color'=>'yellow' ,
      'shape'=>'cylinder')
    */
    if(in_array("apple",$fruit))
    {
       /*Using in_array() function we don't have to worry about array keys. 
         The function checks whether the value exists in given array.
         Returns TRUE if value is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.
         if(in_array("apple",$fruit)) checks for TRUE
       */

       //Do something
    }
}
```

in_array(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

foreach(): http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I tested it and it works.  It is shorter than my answer's code, and it iterated over multiple levels of keys unlike other answers.

Comment: @Fabio: Have updated the solution with explanation. If you still have doubts i am happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```
$hasApple = false;
foreach ($fruits as $subArray) {
    if ($subArray['name'] == "apple")
        $hasApple = true;
}
```

This is the normal solution, simple. You can also try with `array_map($fruits, function () use (&$hasApple) { /* ... */ })`. (but this may be slower...)

As of PHP 5.5 there is an one-liner possible:

```
$hasApple = in_array("apple", array_column($fruits, "name"));
```

Comment: +1 for `array_column`, although with a giant warning: you 'd better be sure it's not a large array, because you will be paying for the one-liner-plus-good-readability convenience with blood. ;-)

Comment: @Jon For little arrays the array_column is about 3 times slower, but for large arrays only 2 times (I just benchmarked it...)

Comment: @Jon `php bench_array_column_in_array.php => 
array_column: 243 secs
foreach: 122 secs` with an array of 3 million entries and looping 100 times (and memory usage is maximum the double size of the array)

Comment: Yeah, for smallish arrays (let's say less than 100 items) I would totally do this in my own code -- in fact I have a custom function that emulates `array_column` and already do. I 'm just saying one needs to be aware of the tradeoffs. Perhaps it sounded more dire than I meant.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$fruits = array(
    array('name'=>'banana', 'color'=>'yellow' , 'shape'=>'cylinder'),
    array('name'=>'apple', 'color'=>'red' , 'shape'=>'sphere'),
    array('name'=>'orange', 'color'=>'orange' , 'shape'=>'sphere') 
);

$result = false;

foreach($fruits as $subarray) {
    if( in_array('apple', $subarray) ) {
        $result = true;
        break;
    }
}

echo "result is ", ($result ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");

?>
```

Comment: What if you search for orange, but apple has orange color?

Comment: It return `true`. Main question was to find any _apple_ in array not to find element which name is _apple_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?PHP


function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$b = array(array('name'=>'banana', 'color'=>'yellow' , 'shape'=>'cylinder'), array('name'=>'apple', 'color'=>'red' , 'shape'=>'sphere'),array('name'=>'orange', 'color'=>'orange' , 'shape'=>'sphere'));
echo in_array_r("apple", $b) ? 'found' : 'not found';

?>
```

[Codepad Demo>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FGsp2C)

Answer (score 0):

```
$hasapple = 0;
foreach($fruits as $keynum)
{
    foreach($keynum as $fruitinfokey => $value)
        {
        if($value == "apple")
            {
            echo "fruits contains " . $value;
            $hasapple = 1;
            }
}
}

if($hasapple == 0)
    {
    echo "The array $fruits does not contain apple";
    }
```

Put a foreach loop inside of another foreach loop to search through expanded keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function arraySearch($value, $array) {
       foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
           if ($val['name'] === $value) {
               return true;
           }
       }
       return null;
    }

if(arraySearch('apple',$fruits)){
   echo "yes found";
}else{
   echo "not found";
}
```

Comment: This is good, but what if I wanted to search a color?  You would have to edit the function.  Make it this: function arraySearch($value,$array,$type = 'name') ... then if($val[$type] === $value.

Comment: no you can pass an another argument in the function arraySearch($value,$array,$type) and check the condition with if($val[$type] === $value)

Comment: That's exactly what I said, except I have $type with a default value, which isn't a necessity.